# bash monstache command not found

Tags: mongodb, elasticsearch, monstache

I have installed monstache service and trying to run the command

monstache -f mongo-elastic.toml &

But getting the below error message

bash: monstache: command not found

How can start the monstache and check the service status on AWS linux machine

Comment: Can you please add the install procedure?

Comment: @skipper21 I was trying to follow the below link https://nehajirafe.medium.com/mongodb-to-elasticsearch-sync-using-monstache-cfe1177594b6

Comment: okay, please check your GOROOT directory bin folder. monstache binary should be available there, just copy it to /usr/local/bin folder.

Comment: in mac the build you can find in /users/<yourusername>/go/bin

Answer (score 1):

try to give exact path of both location

something like this : /opt/monstache/build/linux-amd64/monstache -f /opt/monstache/mongo-elastic.toml &